# Faraday shielding on LIGHT?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light

I am a physics Bachelor student. Faraday shielding was discussed in one of the recent lectures I attended. I wonder if that is true with visible light too.

Light basically being an EM wave should not enter a faraday cage. So if one sets up an experiment with a Faraday cage made of SPECIAL Material which is both conductive and transparent, Will the cage be completely dark inside?

SPECIAL material **: I do realize that transparent and conductive materials rarely exist. Let's assume such a material does exist.

Comment: You can make a box out of cardboard and it will be pretty dark inside if you seal the edges well. What are you trying to do that you can't do with simple materials?

Comment: You're *defining* your material as opaque. How can it possibly be transparent?

Answer (score 1):

> So if one sets up an experiment with a Faraday cage made of SPECIAL Material which is both conductive and transparent, Will the cage be completely dark inside?

To block light, it has to be conductive *at optical frequencies*. If it were, and it blocked light, then we wouldn't call it "transparent".

It is possible to layer different transparent materials to form an [optical coating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_coating), which can be transmissive, reflective, or selectively one or the other at different wavelengths, or when a beam hits it at a certain angle. If you make such a structure in 3-D (rather than simply layering sheets of material) you can call it a [photonic crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photonic_crystal).